# Unable to resolve data for blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, blob, uint8array

I'm trying to convert a Uint8Array to Blob then read Blob with FileReader but I'm getting the following error: Error: Unable to resolve data for blob: (...blob id)

My code looks like following:

```
    const segmentation = await tfModel.segmentPerson(imageTensor);

    const segmentBlob = new Blob([segmentation.data], {type: 'image/jpg'});

    console.log('uInt8Arr', segmentation, 'blob', segmentBlob);

    const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();

    fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
      console.log('start load');
    };

    fileReaderInstance.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('File could not be read: ' + event.target.error);
    };

    fileReaderInstance.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;
      console.log('End Load: BASEEEEEEEEEEE', base64data);
    };

    fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(segmentBlob);

    console.log(fileReaderInstance);
```

Output: [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RvbV.png)

segmentPerson method comes from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/body-pix#returns

I'm on a React Navide environment and I would like to find a way to convert the return from segmentPerson in an image, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you find any answer?